# How can I save output arguments' function generated by a loop in a matrix using scilab?

Tags: function, loops, matrix, save, scilab

(Scilab) 
I'm using a function in a loop. I'd like to save every output argument in a matrix. I can display it but I want to save it.

```
for x = 0:loopduration:(Endtrial-120);
  y = x + 120;
  Deb = x;
  Fin = y;
  Moy = Data_Moy(Data, Deb, Fin);

  disp(Moy); 

end;
```

Comment: What is the size of `Moy` ? Is it a scalar, a vector, a matrix ?

Comment: Moy is a matrix created by a function (Data_Moy)

Comment: Hello, can you validate the answer if it fits your need ?

Answer (score 0):

If `Data_Moy` yields a matrix with fixed sized among iterations I would use a tensor/3D matrix like this:

```
k = 1;
for x = 0:loopduration:(Endtrial-120);
  y = x + 120;
  Deb = x;
  Fin = y;
  Moy(:,:,k) = Data_Moy(Data, Deb, Fin);
  k = k+1;
end;
```

then you can later display or do anything you want with the submatrices e.g

```
disp(Moy(:,:,1))
```